# Example of non-injective functions on $\mathbb R_{\text usual}$

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Show with examples that the assumption that f is injective
is necessary. That is, give an example of a topological space $(X, T)$ and a non-injective function $f : X \to Y$ such that $T_f$ is a topology on $f(X)$, and also give an example where $T_f$ is not a topology; where $T_f$ is defined as $\{f(U) : U \in T\}$
Give both examples in $\mathbb R_{\text usual}$

I have no intuition about this question, if someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. In particular how do we come up with injective functions on open balls in $\mathbb R_{\text usual}$

Answer (score 1):

In very abstract settings (such as algebra and topology), it is always useful to see what happens in the trivial case. Consider the case where $f(X)$ is a point, i.e. $f$ is constant. Then of course $T_f$ is a topology on $f(X)$ (it is the only topology you can put on a point).

If you really want a "real" example, you can take any constant function $f : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$. This gives the point $f(X)$ the subspace topology since the point admits only one possible topology.

An example where $T_f$ is not a topology must be an example where $f(U_1) \cap \cdots \cap f(U_n) \neq f(U_1 \cap \cdots \cap U_n)$ for some open sets $U_1,\cdots,U_n$ since this is the only axiom of a topology that breaks down for $T_f$ (i.e. that a finite intersection of open sets is open) ; it might sometimes make $T_f$ into a topology if $f(U_1) \cap \cdots \cap f(U_n) = f(V)$ for some *other* open set $V$, but of course this is not always the case.

Since you assume $f$ is not injective, there is no point in trying to get "injective functions on open balls" as you claim. The truth is that if $T_f$ happens to be a topology, it is not because of some general facts about $T_f$ but rather because of the particular (class of) example(s) you chose. For instance, you can consider the trivial covering space $f : \mathbb R \times \{0,1\} \to \mathbb R$ (where $\{0,1\}$ is endowed with the discrete topology and $\mathbb R \times \{0,1\}$ with the product topology) ; in this case $T_f$ is the usual topology on the reals. (I said "trivial covering space" to mean that the map $f$ is defined by $f(x,y) = x$ for $y \in \{0,1\}$.)

Feel free to comment if you have trouble finding the example for the last one.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Can you give a simpler example, I can't come up with a non-injective function s.t its image is not a topology

Comment: @jia : I didn't give one. To be honest nothing came to mind since I never thought about a counter-example, I just know what breaks down in the axioms.

Comment: Okay give me some time, i'll think of a counter example and post it and you can tell me if its correct or not :)

Comment: @Sure thing! Feel free to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Have a think about the function that takes all integers to 0, all other  positive reals to 1 and all other negative reals to -1